How to copy a large file to aws lambda
I have created a docker lambda function from cdk and dockerfile contains a line similar to:
COPY models/model.h5 /tmp/weights/model.h5

It creates a directory in lambda tmp/weights/ but not the file.
Expected the file to be there. The model is around 100MB.
Edit:
Apparently for lambda, the tmp directory is cleared in every startup of lambda so the file won't be there even if created during build.

Please add details like dockerfile and debugging steps you have taken.

Default ephemeral storage in /tmp is 512 MB. Did you already use up the available space?
